# Error in inserting pair element in STL queue

Tags: c++, stl, queue, push, c++14

I have a queue of pair elements, which I am using to perform BFS on a rectangular grid. But I get an error in push operation on the  queue, although I perform it similarly elsewhere.

Code:

```
int get_ind(int &ii,int &jj,int i,int j,int x)
{
    queue <pair<int,int> > q;
    q.push({i,j});
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        int ti = q.front().first;
        int tj = q.front().second;
        q.pop();

        for(int p=-1; p<=1; p++)
        {
            for(int q=-1; q<=1; q++)
            {
                ii = ti+p;
                jj = tj+q;
                if(issafe(ii,jj))
                {
                    q.push({ti+p,tj+q});
                    if (arr[ii][jj]==x)
                        return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: request for member 'push' in 'q', which is of non-class type 'int'
                     q.push({ti+p,tj+q});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hide `q` in your loop:

```
queue <pair<int,int> > q;
// later
for(int q=-1; q<=1; q++)
```

Use different variable name in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

The variable **q** has been re-declared as **int** and the same is being used for push operation. Use  different variable either in the below for loop or in the declaration of queue.

```
for(int q=-1; q<=1; q++)
{
    ii = ti+p;
    jj = tj+q;
    if(issafe(ii,jj))
    {
        q.push({ti+p,tj+q});
        if (arr[ii][jj]==x)
            return 0;
    }
}
```

The data type of **q** will be int withing the scope of for loop.